# Draw line chart when ykey value equal 0 and xkeys are months

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

I'm using morris.js to do a line chart in months in xkeys and numeric values in y.

[Chart when y values equal 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2C9w.png)

But when I have all my Y values equal 0, the chart doesn't draw very well.
Someone have the same problem?

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getValuesModel.ashx?id=chart1&refe=" + refe,
    success: function (data) {
        resultschart1 = data;                                    
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'chart1',
            axes: true,
            data: resultschart1,
            xkey: 'mes',
            ykeys: ['valor', 'valorant'],
            labels: [(new Date).getFullYear(), (new Date).getFullYear() - 1],
            parseTime: false,
            barColors: ['#707f9b', '#77709b'],
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        resultschart = "[]";
    }
});
```

**Update 1**

For example my chart receive data this form:

> 0: Object
>   mes: "Jan"
>   valor: 0.47
>   valorant: 0
>   1: Object
>   mes: "Fev"
>   valor: 0.47
>   valorant: 0
>   2: Object
>   mes: "Mar"
>   valor: 0.47
>   valorant: 0
>   3: Object
>   mes: "Abr"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0
>   4: Object
>   mes: "Mai"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0
>   5: Object
>   mes: "Jun"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.51
>   6: Object
>   mes: "Jul"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.48
>   7: Object
>   mes: "Ago"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.48
>   8: Object
>   mes: "Set"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.48
>   9: Object
>   mes: "Out"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.48
>   10: Object
>   mes: "Nov"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.48
>   11: Object
>   mes: "Dez"
>   valor: 0
>   valorant: 0.47

**Update 2**

```
<div id="infoModal1" role="dialog" class="modal fade custom-width" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 96%">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <div id="titulo"></div>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id='dados'></div>
                <h4>Análise da quantidade vendida</h4>
                <div id="chartVenda" style="height: 250px"></div>
                <h4>Variação do preço</h4>
                <div id="chartPreco" style="height: 250px"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function verLinha1(o) {
    var refe = o.getAttribute('name');
    jQuery.ajax({
        //pegando a url apartir da action do form
        url: "clientePreco.aspx/trataModal",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ refe: refe }),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            (function ($) {
                var jsonostr = data.d;
                var jsonobj = eval('(' + jsonostr + ')');

                $("#dados").html("");
                $('#titulo').empty();
                $('#titulo').append("<h3>" + refe + "</h3>")
                $('#dados').empty();
                $("#dados").append("<div class='row'>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Menor Qtt.</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["menorqtt"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Dt. Menor Qtt.</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["menorqttdt"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='row'>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Maior Qtt</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["maiorqtt"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Dt. Maior Qtt</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["maiorqttdt"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='row'>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Média Mensal </div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["mediamensal"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Média Mensal Ano Ant.</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["mediamensalant"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='row'>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Qnt. Total Anual </div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["qtttt"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='col-md-3'>Qnt. Total Anual Ano Ant </div>");
                $("#dados").append("<div class='well well-sm col-md-3'>" + jsonobj["qttttant"] + "</div>");
                $("#dados").append("</div>");

                $('#infoModal1').modal('show');
                var ano = (new Date).getFullYear();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getValuesModel.ashx?id=chartVenda&refe=" + refe,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#chartVenda').empty();

                            resultschart = data;
                            console.log(resultschart);
                            Morris.Line({
                                element: 'chartVenda',
                                data: resultschart,
                                xkey: 'mes',
                                ykeys: ['valor', 'valorant'],
                                labels: [ano, ano - 1],
                                barColors: ['#707f9b', '#77709b'],
                                parseTime: false,
                                resize: true,

                            })
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            resultschart = "[]";
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getValuesModel.ashx?id=chartPreco&refe=" + refe,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#chartPreco').empty();
                            console.log(data);
                            resultschart1 = data;
                            Morris.Line({
                                element: 'chartPreco',
                                axes: true,
                                data: resultschart1,
                                xkey: 'mes',
                                ykeys: ['valor', 'valorant'],
                                labels: [ano, ano - 1],
                                parseTime: false,
                                barColors: ['#707f9b', '#77709b'],
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            resultschart = "[]";
                        }
                    });
                }, 100);
            })(jQuery);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: It should work with 0 ykeys. What version of Morris are you using?

Comment: @jcunham it'd be nice if you took the time to review the answers to your other questions and either accept them or request more information... that'd make people more interested in answering you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the `resize` property to true, to force Morris to redraw the chart when the window size changes:

```
resize: true
```

Add in your `$(document).ready` a window resize function. 
Then `trigger` the resize in the common ajax callback `then`.

Remove your `setTimeout` and put your `show` instruction in a common callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        window.mVenda.redraw();
        window.mPreco.redraw();
    });
});

$.when( 
    $.ajax({
        url: "getValuesModel.ashx?id=chartVenda&refe=" + refe,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#chartVenda').empty();

            resultschart = data;
            console.log(resultschart);
            window.mVenda = Morris.Line({
                element: 'chartVenda',
                data: resultschart,
                xkey: 'mes',
                ykeys: ['valor', 'valorant'],
                labels: [ano, ano - 1],
                barColors: ['#707f9b', '#77709b'],
                parseTime: false,
                resize: true
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            resultschart = "[]";
        }
    }),

    $.ajax({
        url: "getValuesModel.ashx?id=chartPreco&refe=" + refe,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#chartPreco').empty();
            console.log(data);
            resultschart1 = data;
            window.mPreco = Morris.Line({
                element: 'chartPreco',
                axes: true,
                data: resultschart1,
                xkey: 'mes',
                ykeys: ['valor', 'valorant'],
                labels: [ano, ano - 1],
                parseTime: false,
                barColors: ['#707f9b', '#77709b'],
                resize: true
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            resultschart = "[]";
        }
    })
).then(function() {
    $('#infoModal1').modal('show');
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Hello krlzlx, yesterday I realized what was the problem. This chart is print in a modal and I print the chart when the model was hidden. Bur if i draw the chart when the modal is show, the chart will print without problems

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Try my latest answer if not.

Comment: yes I solved the problem with a simple setTimeout(<code>,100);

Comment: Did you try my answer? You should avoid the setTimeout solution.

Comment: Can you add the code with the modal and the html to your question?

Comment: I tried your code, but the result is the same without settimeout

Comment: the big problem is, if the model is hidden so the height and width will be 0, if we draw the charts before the modal show the charts will not well draw

Comment: Ok, try my update. I added a redraw of the charts in the callback. I hope it works this time...

Comment: I'm trying use your code, but i get this message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redraw' of undefined"

Comment: Did you also use these lines of my update: `window.mPreco = Morris.Line({..` and `window.mVenda = Morris.Line({...` ?

Comment: Now yes, but the result it's the same. I really don't understand why this don't work well

Comment: My last update should work, I tested it with a modal. I corrected some lines from my previous update and added a document ready resize function triggered in the common callback. And make sure your Morris.Line have the resize set to true. @jcunham